# Accessing members of the other half of a partial class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, partial-classes, sqlmetal

I'm just learning to work with partial classes in VB.NET and VS2008. Specifically, I'm trying to extend a LINQ to SQL class that was automatically created by SqlMetal.

The automatically generated class looks like this:

```
Partial Public Class DataContext
    Inherits System.Data.Linq.DataContext

 ...


<Table(Name:="dbo.Concessions")>  _
Partial Public Class Concession

 ...

     <Column(Storage:="_Country", DbType:="Char(2)")>  _
   Public Property Country() As String
          ...
    End Property

 ...

End Class
```

In a separate file, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Partial Public Class DataContext

    Partial Public Class Concession

        Public Function Foo() as String
            Return DoSomeProcessing(Me.Country)
        End Function

    End Class

End Class
```

... but I get blue jaggies under '`Me.Country`' and the message **`'Country' is not a member of 'DataContext.Concession'`**. Both halves of the partial class are in the same namespace.

So how do I access the properties of the automatically-generated half of the partial class, from my half of the partial class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless VB.NET generates different stuff in its LINQ to SQL files from C# the classes of the DB tables aren't within the DataContext class, just beside it.

So you have the class **MyNamespace.DataContext.Concession** when the other half of the partial class is realy **MyNamespace.Concession**

Answer (score 0):

(This related to VB.NET - might be differences with C# projects)

I put my entities in their own namespace by configuring the Linq-to-SQL model property.

e.g. MyCo.MyProj.Business.Entities

I then add non-Linq business entities in there too, so they are all in the same namespace.

However, when trying to do the above partial class additions, I found that the partial class (i.e. the one you generate, not the auto-generated LINQ class) MUST be in the same project as the Linq-to-SQL model. Otherwise in the Class View and Object Viewer you see two separate classes - seemingly in the same namespace, but not really. Not sure if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong.

But, anyway, putting the partial class file in the same project as your model works.